# Hadamard product of a positive semidefinite matrix with a negative definite matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-semidefinite, hadamard-product

If I have a positive semidefinite matrix $A$ and a negative definite matrix $B$, is it true that their Hadamard product $A\circ B$ is negative semidefinite? Ideally I am looking for a proof / a complete argument for why it is true / false that I can replicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) states that Hadamard product of two positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite.

$B$ is negative definite $\implies -B$ is positive definite.

Since $$A \circ B = -(A \circ (-B)),$$  and $A \circ (-B)$ is positive semidefinite by Schur product theorem.

We conclude that  $A \circ B$ is negative semidefinite.

Comment: This is only true if the dimension of the matrices $A$ and $B$ is odd, correct? Else multiplying them by the negative identity leaves their determinant unchanged.

Comment: a negative definite matrix can have a positive determinant. For example $-I_2$, the negative of the identity matrix of size $2$.

Comment: Ah sorry, i think I am using a different definition. Ive also found a counter example to this arguement. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Here $A$ and $A\circ B$ are positive definite, $B$ is not. Any positive definite diagonal matrix will do in place of $A$, and it even still works if the off-diagonal entries of $A$ are nonzero but small.

Comment: Note that your $B$ is not negative definite.